# Backbone.js: Disallow backbone history

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational, backbone-routing

I came on this site to research a problem that I've been having regarding negating Backbone.js's history for certain elements. Thankfully, I came across this answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338207/how-do-i-disable-backbone-history-but-still-allow-hash-based-routing).

While it had provided a solution for me, the ultimate result was partial.

**PROBLEM:**

I am using Backbone.js for my navigation. I navigate to a route called "Portfolio" and then a number of images show up which can then be clicked again to view information. In order to render this information, I have it going through another route. The aforementioned resolution had me assigning the following code to negate these Portfolio links from being part of the History:

```
$(this).bind('click', function(e){
    theSiteController.navigate('portfolio/portfolioSelection/' + i, {trigger:true, replace: true }); 
});
```

I had applied **replace: false** to the **.navigate** and it worked: whenever I hit the Back button, I would skip back to the origin page that I came from. HOWEVER, when I hit the Forward button in my browser, it points me back to the Portfolio link that I had clicked before, which looks like this:

```
#portfolio/portfolioSelection/4
```

I have it set to a different View, so I'm wondering if that has something to do with it.

**QUESTION:**

When I click the Forward button in my browser, how would I re-route it so that way it goes to

`#portfolio`

instead of

```
#portfolio/portfolioSelection/4
```

To view the site, please click [here](http://www.tsaconas.com/html5/bootstrap/).

I apologize if this has been answered, but I can't seem to find a proper resolution.

Thank you, in advance, for your help!

Comment: Backbone doesn't have the tools to do what you want (and the replace tag isn't appropriate either, as it erases #portfolio from the history and put #portfolio/portfolioSelection/4 instead), and sadly, doesn't have much routing tools. You should consider using only models and views instead of routing (if you don't want it in the history, routing is probably not the answer).

Comment: I was worried about that. It sucks because I like what the History is doing for the remainder of the site, but not specifically for this part. Also, it's true that Backone is still rather limited when it comes to routing tools. Personally, their documentation isn't a favourite of mine to read.

I was thinking of putting the portfolio object load into a click event, but I want to avoid using a link altogether.

Comment: Quite the opposite for me actually, I like their doc and the code's pretty easy to read imo. About what to do, your pictures could easily be the elements of views, then listening to the clicks is pretty natural. Well, there are tons of ways to do it, I'm pretty sure you'll find one that suits you :)

Comment: I think I got it: I removed the "replace: true", removed the href attribute, applied a preventDefault() to the event, and it works fine.  While I had removed the href attribute, I applied the tabindex attribute to increase its accessibility. Thanks for your help!