# Exclude a specific url from backbone history

Tags: backbone.js

Does anyone know, how to not register a specific url in backbone history? I mean the url will be there in the router with a function associated with it, Because my app has a back button, I just don't want to register it in backbone history.

Comment: Never mind got the answer 
[here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338207/how-do-i-disable-backbone-history-but-still-allow-hash-based-routing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer

```
app.navigate('posts/1/edit',{trigger:true, replace: true});
```

[Check the original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338207/how-do-i-disable-backbone-history-but-still-allow-hash-based-routing)